# Subgroups and The Quaternion Group

Tags: group-theory, quaternions

I'm working on a rather difficult question. Perhaps somewhat could shed some light as to what I'm suppose to do:

**Question: How many subgroups of index $2$ does the quaternion group have and what are they?**

We haven't had much practice with using the quaternion group at all. Although, we have been focusing more on the Klein-$4$ group but that's not the point. From what I understand, upon doing some internet browsing, that the quaternion group has order $8$ since

$$Q = \{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}.$$

Now, if I  were to have a subgroup, call it $H$, such that it has index $2$ in, say, group $G$, it would mean that half of the elements in $G$ lie in $H$. So am I suppose to find all the subgroups of the quaternion group, then chose which ones have index $2$? How would one begin to answer this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the orders of the **elements** of $Q$:

- $1$ has order $1$
- $-1$ has order $2$
- the other elements all have order $4$

Up to isomorphism there are only two types of subgroups of order $4$, namely $\mathbb Z_4$ or $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. The latter has three elements of order $2$, which is impossible in $Q$. So any subgroup of order $4$ must be cyclic. By inspection, the only possibilities are $\langle i \rangle$, $\langle j \rangle$, and $\langle k \rangle$.

---

**Edit** to sketch a proof of the statement about the possible types of group of order $4$:

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $4$. If $G$ contains an element of order $4$, then $G$ is cyclic, hence isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$.

The only other possibility is that $G$ does not contain an element of order $4$, in which case all of its non-identity elements must have order $2$ (Lagrange). Let $a$ and $b$ be two such elements.

Then $A = \langle a \rangle$ and $B = \langle b \rangle$ are subgroups of order $2$, hence index $2$, hence they are both normal.

Thus $AB$ is also a subgroup, and it contains $a$, $b$, and the identity, so its order is at least $3$. By Lagrange, its order must be $4$, hence $G = AB$. Since $A$ and $B$ are both normal subgroups and $A \cap B = 1$, this is a direct product.

Thus we have exposed $G$ as the direct product $A \times B$. As $A$ and $B$ have order $2$, they are both isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$, which shows that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ as claimed.

Comment: slick. I should study more about the classification of low order finite groups...

Comment: Definitely saving this problem as one of my favorites.

Answer (score 2):

Since the quaternions are a finite group of order $8$, Lagrange's theorem implies the only possible proper subgroups of $Q_8$ are of orders $2$ and $4$. Furthermore the only subgroups of index $2$ are of order $4$. Since $1$ must be an element of any subgroup then there are only $7$ choose $3$ (= $35$) more possibilities. Almost certainly $-1$ is also an element of at least one index-2 subgroup. I would only know of checking the rest by hand.

Three are clearly $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$, $\{\pm 1,\pm j\}$, and $\{\pm 1,\pm k\}$.

Comment: I see. What makes a subgroup "proper"? I feel like we haven't discussed that in my class just yet, but we will soon get there. for clarification purposes, Lagrange's Theorem, in a nutshell, says that the order of a subgroup is a divisor of the order of a group correct?

Comment: Correct on Lagrange's theorem. A proper subgroup is just a subgroup not equal to the original group. It is a convenient way of getting away from trivial examples (e.g. "does a group $G$ always have a subgroup? "sure, $G$ is a subgroup of $G$! "ok, duh, but any *proper* subgroups?" "well, the identity is always a subgroup :3" "OK, *proper, nontrivial* subgroups?").

Comment: I see. Some clarification: what does it mean when a subgroup has, for example, index $3$, instead of $2$? I reading [this link that I have hyperlinked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup) They mentioned something about cosets. How would that be relevant here, if it *is*?

Comment: The index of a subgroup is exactly the cardinality of the set of cosets of that subgroup. The axiom of choice permits you to select a representative from each coset, the set of which is sometimes called the transversal of the group. The cardinality of the transversal is then the same as the index of the subgroup. If $G$ is finite and $H \leq G$ then $|G| = |G:H||H|$, which is why an order 4 subgroup of an order 8 group must have index-2.

Comment: BTW @Bungo's answer has shown the three subgroups I original gave are the only ones of index-2. His argument relies on the happy occurrence that many mathematicians have worked hard for hundreds of years to completely classify all finite groups up to isomorphism.

Comment: Yes I have noticed that from Bungo's answer. That's really clever.

Comment: Fortunately, classifying all groups of order $4$ is pretty easy :-) I'll add a proof sketch for completeness.

Comment: Sounds good Bungo.

Comment: $7 \text{ choose } 3$ equals $35$, not $7$